# Who can help what is wrong with this contract and codes?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

```
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

You can see the Error in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pragma solidity 0.8.0;` at the top of the .sol file. This is how you choose your solidity language version.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I just change the silidity version to 0.8.0 then that error gone, but another just poped up, the Error is :  ParserError: expected identifier but got 'public'                     and this the code: mapping(address => uint256) public depositedTime;
    function deposit(uint256 amount) public {
    depositedTime[msg.sender] = block.timestamp;
    YOUR_LOGIC;

Comment: Could you please attach the full contract code here? It's hard for me like this.

Comment: Sorry about it, the last one get fixed too, but again the next error is  ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected, for this code:             contract TestDef is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

Comment: And once again, I cannot help you if you don't attach the **full** contract code.

Comment: Oh, ok, should Copy and paste entire contract here?

Comment: Or even better paste it at https://pastebin.com/ and drop me the link here